# Nagios Temperature - Plugin not working

Tags: graph, monitoring, nagios, temperature

Hello I noticed that in the nagios is not possible to draw temperature information on the graph.
Is there any solution how to do that ? 
I found plugin check_snmp_temperature but is not available in the menu.
Is there anybody who can help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to try out the [Community Edition of Pandora FMS](http://pandorafms.org). I'm monitoring the ambient CPU and have a Telegram alert if it goes beyond 60 ºC.

[image: Pandora FMS temperature monitoring]